# Is my NVIDIA GT 540M having a hardware failure?

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, nvidia-geforce, discrete-graphics

I'm using a Sager NP5160 laptop, which has an NVIDIA GT 540M dGPU as well as integrated graphics. I'm dual-booting Windows 7 and Linux Mint. I've recently noticed issues with games not performing as well as they should when I switch to balanced mode (from UMA mode) in Windows 7. After looking into the Device Details, it appears it's getting a code 43. In some places I read this was a hardware issue that I would need to send my laptop in for, in others that it was possibly a driver issue only. I tried reinstalling drivers, both from the NVIDIA site, and from the original Sager disk, neither of which fixed the issue.

I then tried running `optirun glxgears` on Mint to see if my graphics card was working in Linux at all. This gave me:

```
[ 1693.231169] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.  Please
[ 1693.231258] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Running lspci does detect my card:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
```

Checking the kernel log, it seems that Bumblebee successfully finds and tries to boot the card, but then it fails to initialize:

```
Dec 27 10:50:00 RmRfSlash kernel: [  501.993242] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.305585] pci 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.305603] pci 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.305657] pci 0000:01:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x100006, writing 0x100000)
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.305685] pci 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.305692] pci 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.305701] pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.305717] pci 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.305727] pci 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.543867] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.543873] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.593722] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.593733] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.593744] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.593760] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.593777] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.593788] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
Dec 27 10:50:01 RmRfSlash kernel: [  502.594061] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  295.40  Thu Apr  5 21:37:00 PDT 2012
Dec 27 10:50:04 RmRfSlash kernel: [  505.462708] NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x27:0xffffffff:1190)
Dec 27 10:50:04 RmRfSlash kernel: [  505.462717] NVRM: rm_init_adapter(0) failed
```

It seems like it might be a hardware problem, but I wanted to see if anyone had a suggested fix before I deal with the hassle of sending in my laptop.

Thanks!